# Subgroups and cyclic groups

Tags: cyclic-groups

Suppose a group $G$ has no proper subgroups (that is, the only subgroup
of $G$ is $G$ itself and the trivial subgroup $\{e\}$. Show that $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: Take any $g\in G$ different from the identity element. What is $\langle g\rangle$?

Comment: Let $x\in G$, then $\langle x\rangle=G$ unless $x=e$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** For any $g\in G$, we have $\langle g\rangle\subseteq G$, where $\langle g \rangle$ is the cyclic group generated by $g$.